# Hide image when its value is NULL or Empty in JasperReports

Tags: image, jasper-reports

I am using JasperReports 6.2.2 version. I want to hide image if the value is null or empty.

Below code I used in jrxml to hide the image, but this doesn't work for me.

```
<image>
    <reportElement x="33" y="0" width="88" height="45" uuid="182b40f8-b18e-417c-b9f4-096199533567">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($F{urlImage}!=null ? $F{urlImage} : "")]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
</image>
```

**$F{urlImage} is of String type**

It gives an error

```
ERROR [btpool0-2] (JRFillSubreport.java:866) - Fill 1: exception
     [java] java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluatePrintWhenExpression(JRFillElement.java:806)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluate(JRFillImage.java:471)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:381)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillFrame.evaluate(JRFillFrame.java:159)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:381)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:500)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2022)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:748)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:255)
     [java] java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluatePrintWhenExpression(JRFillElement.java:806)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluate(JRFillImage.java:471)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:381)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillFrame.evaluate(JRFillFrame.java:159)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:381)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:500)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2022)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:748)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:255)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:115)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:580)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:414)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:736)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:221)
     [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:115)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:580)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:414)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:736)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
     [java]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:221)
     [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How to hide the image if its value is null or empty. In urlImage field contains the url of the image. For example: "[http://use.example.com/pop.png][1]".

Comment: Image element has property for ignoring the error. In this case (error) it will be just empty. You can try to write your own scriptlet and use it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`printWhenExpression`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/schema.reference.html#printWhenExpression) should return a `Boolean`, currently you are returning a `String`

`$F{urlImage}!=null ? $F{urlImage} : ""` is a [ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) expression that returns value of `$F{urlImage}` if not null otherwise and empty String

Instead you need just to return a `Boolean` so you will need an expression like this:

```
<printWhenExpression>
    <![CDATA[$F{urlImage}!=null && !$F{urlImage}.isEmpty()]]>    
</printWhenExpression>
```

<sup>Print when not null and not empty</sup>

> **Note:** Using old jasper-reports lib it will not [autobox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) automatically
>   you need to create the Boolean object yourself
>
> `new Boolean($F{urlImage}!=null && !$F{urlImage}.isEmpty())`

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in the Jaspersoft Studio:

[image]

Which creates following line in the jrxml:

`<image isUsingCache="true" onErrorType="Blank">`

Comment: Its not a solution of my problem but still somewhere else it help me.. Thankyou